# My html page is shifted to the left but i can't see where the problem is

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello I choose a template to work with, it was fine at the beginning but after some modification, I cannot see where I messed it up, the whole page is moved to the left but I don't know where is the problem.

[image]
The HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  ......stuff
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="51">
    <!-- Nav Bar Start -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href=""> <img src="img/mylogo2.png" width="80px"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarCollapse">
                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    .... nav stuff
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Bar End -->

    <!-- Hero Start -->
    <div class="hero" id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-4">
                    <div class="hero-content">
                        <div class="hero-text">
                            <p>Welcome To </p>
                            <h1>{{ strtoupper($heros->title) }}</h1>
                            <h2></h2>
                            <div class="typed-text">
                                <p style="color:#ED428B;"> {{ $heros->content }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hero-btn mt-4">
                            <a class="btn" href="">Hire Us</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a class="btn" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class="hero-image">
                        <img src="images/{{$heros->img}}" alt="Hero Image" width="600px" height="600px">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hero End -->

    <!-- Service Start -->
    <div class="service" id="service">
        <div class="container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Service End -->


    <!-- Banner Start -->
    <div class="banner wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
        <div class="container">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Banner End -->

    <!-- Portfolio Start -->
    <p>..............................</p>
        
    <!-- Portfolio End -->


    <!-- Banner Start -->
    <div class="banner wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
        <div class="container">
            ....banner
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Banner End -->


    <!-- Price Start -->
    <div class="price" id="price">
        .....
    </div>
    <!-- Price End -->



    <!-- Testimonial Start -->
    <div class="testimonial wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" id="review">
        <div class="text-center wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
            .....test...stuff
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Testimonial End -->
    

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <div class="footer shape wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           ......footer stuff
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer End -->

    <!-- Back to top button -->
    <a href="#" class="btn back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>

    <!-- Pre Loader -->
    <div id="loader" class="show">
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script>//....some script</script>
</body>

<style>
    .brands {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 90px;
        padding-bottom: 90px
    }

    .brands_slider_container {
        height: 130px;
        border: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        padding-left: 97px;
        padding-right: 97px;
        background: #fff
    }

    .brands_slider {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .brands_item {
        height: 150px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .brands_item img {
        width: 50px;
        height: 85px;
    }

    .brands_nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer
    }

    .brands_nav i {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
        transition: all 200ms ease
    }

    .brands_nav:hover i {
        color: #676767
    }

    .brands_prev {
        left: 40px;
    }

    .brands_next {
        right: 40px
    }
</style>

</html>
```

and the css
excuse me if it a lot of code but I want to host this app as soon as possible cuz I already paid for the hosting.

```
body {
    color: #797979;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1,
h2, 
h3, 
h4,
h5, 
h6 {
    color: #414141;
}

a {
    color: #313131;
    transition: .3s;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
    color: #009FF9;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus,
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.container-fluid {
    max-width: 1366px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 12px 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #009FF9;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #009FF9;
    transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
}


.btn:hover {
    color: #009FF9;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #009FF9;
    border-color: #009FF9;
}

#loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out, visibility 0s linear .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-out, visibility 0s linear .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-out, visibility 0s linear .3s;
    z-index: 999;
}

#loader.show {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-out, visibility 0s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-out, visibility 0s linear 0s;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-out, visibility 0s linear 0s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#loader .loader {
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 5px solid #dddddd;
    border-top: 5px solid #009FF9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 9;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.back-to-top i {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.back-to-top:hover i {
    color: #414141;
}
/*********** Nav Bar CSS **********/
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar.nav-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: .5s;
    
}

.navbar .navbar-brand img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 40px;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #f8f9fa;
}

/********** Hero CSS ***********/

.hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    padding: 120px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(#009FF9, #ffffff), url(../img/hero-bg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.hero .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}

.hero .hero-image {
    position: relative;
    /* text-align: right; */
    /* padding-right: 75px; */
    padding-right: 4em;
}

.hero .hero-image img {
  
}

.hero .hero-content {
    margin-top: -12em;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.hero .hero-text p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.hero .hero-text h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.hero .hero-text h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.hero .hero-text .typed-text {
    display: none;
}

.hero .hero-text .typed-cursor {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.hero .hero-btn .btn {
    margin-top: 35px;
    color: #009FF9;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #ffffff;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.hero .hero-btn .btn:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
}

.hero .hero-btn .btn:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/******* Section Header ********/
.section-header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.section-header p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.section-header p::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    top: 11px;
    right: 0;
    left: -30px;
    background: #009FF9;
    z-index: -1;
}

.section-header p::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    top: 11px;
    left: 3px;
    background: #009FF9;
    z-index: 1;
}

.section-header h2 {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/********** About CSS **********/
.about {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -45px 0 45px 0;
}

.about .col-lg-6 {
    padding: 0;
}

.about .section-header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about .about-img {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.about .about-img img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.about .about-content {
    padding: 0 60px;
}

.about .about-text p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.about .skills {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about .skill-name {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.about .skill-name p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.about .skill-name p:last-child {
    float: right;
}

.about .progress {
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #dddddd;
}

.about .progress .progress-bar {
    width: 0px;
    background: #009FF9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 2s;
}

.about .about-text a.btn {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

/******* Experience CSS ********/
.experience {
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.experience .timeline {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.experience .timeline::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    background: #009FF9;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item {
    position: relative;
    background: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.left {
    left: 0;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.right {
    left: 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 48px;
    right: -8px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #009FF9;
    border-radius: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.right::after {
    left: -8px;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 46px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #dddddd;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.right::before {
  left: 10px;
  border-color: transparent #dddddd transparent transparent;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-date {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 44px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #009FF9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.left .timeline-date {
    text-align: left;
    left: calc(100% + 55px);
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.right .timeline-date {
    text-align: right;
    right: calc(100% + 55px);
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-text {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 5px solid #dddddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-item.right .timeline-text {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 5px solid #dddddd;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-text h2 {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-text h4 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.experience .timeline .timeline-text p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/********* Service CSS *********/
.service {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.service .service-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}

.service .service-item:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 800px 0 0 0 #009FF9;
}

.service .service-icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #009FF9;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon i {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #009FF9;
    transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover i {
    font-size: 75px;
}

.service .service-text {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.service .service-text h3 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 1s;
}

.service .service-text p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 1s;
}

/******** Portfolio CSS ********/
.portfolio {
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-filter {
    padding: 0;
    margin: -15px 0 25px 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-filter li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #009FF9;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #009FF9;
    transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
}

.portfolio #portfolio-filter li:hover,
.portfolio #portfolio-filter li.filter-active {
    color: #009FF9;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #009FF9;
    border-color: #009FF9;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item {
    position: relative;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-img {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-img img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: cover;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .5s;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item:hover img {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-text {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin: -30px 15px 30px 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.portfolio .portfolio-text h3 {
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-text a.btn {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 0 2px 1px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 100;
    border-radius: .1em;
}

.portfolio .portfolio-item:hover a.btn {
    color: #009FF9;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #009FF9;
    border-color: #009FF9;
}

/********* Banner CSS **********/
.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 45px 0;
    padding: 90px 0;
    background: #009FF9;
}

.banner .container {
    max-width: 750px;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner .section-header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.banner .section-header p {
    color: #414141;
    background: transparent;
}

.banner .section-header p::after {
    display: none;
}

.banner .section-header h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.banner .section-header h2 span {
    color: #414141;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.banner .banner-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.banner .banner-text .btn {
    margin-top: 15px;
    color: #009FF9;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #ffffff;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

/********* Pricing CSS *********/
.price {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.price .row {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.price .col-md-4 {
    padding: 0;
}

.price .price-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.price .featured-item {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.price .price-header,
.price .price-body,
.price .price-footer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.price .price-header {
    padding: 45px 0 30px 0;
    color: #414141;
}

.price .price-item.featured-item .price-header {
    color: #009FF9;
}

.price .price-title h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price .price-prices h2 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 small {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 span {
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.price .price-item.featured-item h2 {
    color: #009FF9;
}

.price .price-body {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.price .price-description ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.price .price-description ul li {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.price .price-item .price-action {
    padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.price .price-item .price-action .btn {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #414141;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #414141;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.price .price-item .price-action .btn:hover {
    color: #414141;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #414141;
    border-color: #414141;
}

.price .price-item.featured-item .price-action .btn {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #009FF9;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #009FF9;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

/*********** Team CSS **********/
.team {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.team .team-item {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.team .team-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: .3em;
}

.team .team-img img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s;
}

.team .team-text {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.team .team-text h2 {
    color: #009FF9;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.team .team-text h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.team .team-text p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.team .team-social {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
}

.team .team-social a.btn {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: .2em;
}

.team .team-item:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 800px 0 0 0 #009FF9;
}

.team .team-item:hover .team-img img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.team .team-item:hover .team-text h2,
.team .team-item:hover .team-text h4,
.team .team-item:hover .team-text p {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.team .team-item:hover .team-social a.btn {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.team .team-item:hover .team-social a.btn:hover {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
/******* Testimonial CSS *******/
.testimonial {
    position: relative;
    margin: 45px 0;
    padding: 90px 0;
    background: #009FF9;
}

.testimonial .container {
    max-width: 900px;
    
}

.testimonial .testimonial-icon {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .testimonial-icon i {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .5);
}

.testimonial .testimonial-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .testimonial-img {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.testimonial .testimonial-item img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    /* border: 5px dotted #ffffff; */
    /* border-radius: 100px; */
}



/********* Contact CSS *********/

.contact {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 45px 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.contact .container-fluid {
    background: url(../img/mail.png) left center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.contact .contact-form {
    position: relative;
    padding: 90px 0 90px 45px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.contact .contact-form input {
    color: #8d8d8d;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8d8d8d;
}

.contact .contact-form textarea {
    color: #5a5151;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8d8d8d;
}

.contact .contact-form .form-control::placeholder {
    color: #747474;
    opacity: 1;
}

.contact .contact-form .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder,
.contact .contact-form .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #8d8d8d;
}

/*********** Blog CSS **********/
.blog {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 45px 0 15px 0;
}

.blog .blog-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.blog .blog-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blog .blog-img img {
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s;
}

.blog .blog-item:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.blog .blog-text {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

.blog .blog-text h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.blog .blog-text p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blog .blog-item a.btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}

.blog .blog-item a.btn i {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.blog .blog-meta {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.blog .blog-meta p {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.blog .blog-meta i {
    color: #414141;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.blog .blog-meta p:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
/********* Footer CSS **********/
.footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 45px;
    /* background: #009FF9; */
}

.footer .container-fluid {
    padding: 60px 0 0 0;
}

.footer .footer-info {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer .footer-info h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer .footer-info h3 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer .footer-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer .footer-menu p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.footer .footer-menu p:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.footer .footer-social {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .footer-social a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer .footer-social a i {
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: .3s;
}

.footer .footer-social a:last-child i {
    margin: 0;
}

.footer .footer-social a:hover i {
    color: #414141;
}

.footer .copyright {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.footer .copyright::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
    background: rgba(256, 256, 256, .2);
}




enter image description here
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a link to a JSFiddle, CodeSandBox, or CodePen

Comment: Browser inspector is a great tool to know where you made mistake

Comment: Can you share a live version of the page? Investigating using the browser inspector is probably the best way to see what's happening.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I just knew where the problem was i added this to the body

```
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

and it's solved the problem credit to this user

> omma2289